# Adapt proof of Lagrange theorem

Tags: group-theory

I am asked to solve the following problem (it is exercise 11.11 of Armstrong's Groups and symmetry):

IF $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ and if $|G|=m|H|$, adapt the proof of Lagrange's theorem to show that $g^{m!}\in H$ for all $g\in G$

I have no clue how to tackle this problem so could anyone please send me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider the set of cosets of $H$, and how multiplication with $g$ operates on that set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to consider the set $X$ of all cosets of $H$. Then $G$ acts by multiplication on $X$ and so there is a homomorphism $G \to Sym(X)$. By Lagrange's theorem, $g^{m!}$ acts as the identity. In particular $g^{m!}H =H$ and so $g^{m!}\in H$.